# Could not load google tag manager with 404 error

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a new project to set up Google tag manager. The new preview experience allows me to add the domain and open up in a new browser tab which is kind of cool, however, I got back with this error in the chrome dev tool

```
GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=myGTMID net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

where myGTMID is the id of my GTM from my newly created account.

I also try to open this URL https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=myGTMID manually it gave me the same error which is expected.

Is there anything I missed in the config inside the GTM console? Is there anyone experiencing this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within Google Tag Manager itself. Your browser is requesting data from Google's servers although that container is still not published yet, thus no data will be returned.

The **solution** here is to **publish Google Tag Manager container** once you create it.

Comment: Simple mistake. GTM should not allow previewing if the tag has not been published to avoid this issue. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

9 out of 10 times this issue occurs when you did not publish your workspace.
[image: GTM Submit and publish changes]